# MediaPlayer component configuration issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can not find a working sample of a video playing in WPF.

The most obvious sample, that I'd expect to work, is in the official WPFSamples repo: 
https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Sample%20Applications/VideoViewerDemo

However, when I deploy and run this, I get no compile errors or runtime errors. However the video simply does not appear.

"Please can someone indicate what might be wrong with my approach on the configuration of running the official sample of the WPF MediaPlayer class?"

The specific code, as from the WPFSample repositiory is as follows:

In [MainWindow.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/VideoViewerDemo/MainWindow.xaml):

```
<MediaElement Name="mainVideo" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=Source}" />
```

And this is bound to [MyVideo.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/VideoViewerDemo/MyVideo.cs), using:

```
    public class MyVideo
    {
        private string _name;
        private Uri _source;

        public MyVideo(string path)
        {
            Source = path;
            _source = new Uri(path);
        }

        public MyVideo(string path, string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            Source = path;
            _source = new Uri(path);
        }

        public string VideoTitle
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public string Source { get; }
    }
```

I'm not questioning this, but I believe this is using the [NETCore3.1 MediaPlayer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=netcore-3.1), at least, it builds into \VideoViewerDemo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ and the Target framework in the Project Application configuration is .NET Core 3.1.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.5.4.
I have a clean, Windows 10 Pro Version 1906 for x64-based systems.

Comment: I posted a screen video capture here that clearly shows the problem:
https://youtu.be/qe0q-N2Qlxc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Windows Media Player using the Windows 10 "Turn Windows features on or off" window. This is not installed by default on Windows 10, and Microsoft documentation does not indicate this dependency.

[image]

Comment: It is very strange because I did enable/disable my wmp yesterday when I was troubleshooting (which was initially disabled) and I was still able to play wmv files into movies & TV application either-way. But anyway good that this fix your problem.